# Emacs client starts in no windows mode

Tags: emacsclient, server

I have the following in `.bashrc`.

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"
```

When I run, for example

```
emacsclient something.tex &
```

when running X, in a Konsole terminal (Konsole is the KDE X term client), the file opens up inside the Konsole terminal displaying the file (as though I had called `-nw`), when it should start up an emacs X frame. Also, the file is not normally editable. I cannot type, and when  enter it behaves like I am still in the terminal, except the cursor jumps around on the screen when I try to type, and `echo $TERM` still gives `xterm`. Also, I'm seeing stuff like `Auto-saving...done` at the bottom of the terminal. Checking the processes gives

```
$ ps aux | grep emacs
faheem   31260  0.0  0.0  12516   800 pts/2    S    17:40   0:00 emacsclient something.tex
faheem   31269  0.2  0.1 230896 27408 ?        Ss   17:40   0:01 emacs --daemon
```

After further investigation, it seems the backgrouding `&`. Is causing the problem. Leaving it out causes emacs to open in `-nw` mode. But I want a full X emacs frame. Why is it not doing that?

I see the `-c` option says

```
-c, --create-frame
          create a new frame instead of trying to use the current Emacs frame
```

and this does create a emacs X frame, but if there is no existing frame, why doesn't it create one instead of opening in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-c` option to force opening a new graphical frame.

Comment: So I discovered. See my most recent edit. But why doesn't it do this by default?

Comment: You're free to read `server.el` and scratch your head why it's behaving that way by default. If you find something that feels bug-like, you can use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to discuss it on the debbugs mailing list.

Comment: Well, presumably it has some reason for behaving this way. I just wonder what it is.

Comment: @FaheemMitha well, if you don't have a graphical frame opened and you invoked the command in a smart terminal, the safe assumption is that you want to edit the file right there. If you do have a graphical frame open, I think the client will default to using that.

Comment: @Malabarba that isn't consistent with the behavior of the `emacs` command itself. `emacs` creates a frame. why doesn't `emacsclient`? By the principle of least surprise, it should, imo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the two are not on an equal footing. Before running the `emacsclient` command, you always have to run the `emacs` command. Whether you start emacs with or without a graphical frame, the `emacsclient` command is simply respecting the choice you made with the `emacs` command.

Comment: @FaheemMitha of course this won't always be right, but it's the best bet.

Comment: @Malabarba maybe I'm missing something, but with the settings in my question, `emacsclient` starts up the `emacs` server if it doesn't exist. So, why not just start up a new frame while it is about it?

Comment: When I try this, emacs still opens in no windows mode, and says "`Unknown option ‘-c’`" (in this small space below where you type which I can never remember the name of).

Comment: Yes, because the option is for `emacsclient`, not `emacs`. Running `emacs -c` gives me exactly that error and that's to be expected because the question is about `emacsclient`.